# Highlight bash output in iTerm 2?

Tags: macos, bash, iterm2, iterm, solarized

I've followed the instructions for [installing Solarized on iTerm 2](https://github.com/altercation/solarized/tree/master/iterm2-colors-solarized#installation), on my new OSX Yosemite machine. It looks as though the background and basic colours are being applied, and `$TERM` produces `xterm-256color`.

However, everything is very monochrome. How can I get iTerm to highlight the output in a more helpful way?

[image]

Comment: what do you expect to be colorized? try `ls -G`.  It seems that solarized is a set of color schemes. IT doesn't make your commands do colorization.  You may need to check your `vim` settings as well

Comment: I was hoping that the details of `ls -al` would be colorized in a useful way. I've followed the instructions for setting up Solarized with vim here: http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/vim-colors-solarized - I now have nice colours in vim, but I still have a very monochrome GUI.

Comment: I think the section "IMPORTANT NOTE FOR TERMINAL USERS" on http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/vim-colors-solarized might be relevant ("If you are going to use Solarized in Terminal mode...") but I can't understand what it's asking me to do.

Comment: This may also be relevant, as it's how I installed solarized: https://github.com/altercation/solarized/tree/master/iterm2-colors-solarized

Comment: As I said before, You need to add the G flag (on Mac OS X) for it to colonize.

Comment: I use in my *`.bashrc`* the following alias: `alias ls="/bin/ls --color -lF"`

Comment: @F.Hauri why are you specifying the path to `ls`?  That should be in your `PATH`.  And the `--color` option is for GNU `ls`.  For the builtin BSD `ls`, `ls -lGF` should be used

Comment: @MaxCoplan to prevent use of previously defined *alias* or *function*. By spefifying the path, I ensure `/bin/ls` and nothing else, will be used.